# How to detach a forked process from parent in C

Tags: c, shell, unix, exec, fork

So i am designing a basic UNIX shell in C.

```
    signal(SIGCHLD, handler);
        pid = fork();
        switch (pid) {
        case -1: printf("Fork failed; cpid == -1\n");
        break;

        case 0: child_pid = getpid();
                argv[0] = prog;
        argv[1] =NULL;
        //exit(0);
        sid = setsid();
        execv(absPath,argv);        
        //printf("%d: this is the child, pid = %d\n", i, child_pid);
        //sleep(1);
        //exit(0);
        break;

        default: printf("This is the parent: waiting for %d to finish\n", pid);
        waitpid(pid, NULL, WNOHANG);
        printf("Ttttthat's all, folks\n");
        //break;
        }
        //execv(absPath,argv);
        //printf("CHILD PROCESS");
    }

}
void handler(int sig)
{
  pid_t pid;

  pid = wait(NULL);

  printf("Pid %d exit.\n", pid);
  exit(0);
}
```

But it still executes the forked process in the same shell, though after the "default" clause.

Can you please help me make it run as a background process? Thanks!

P.S: This is just a snippet.

Comment: First of all your case 0: is odd you have an exit(0) in there.

Your logic in the snippet feels bizarre

Comment: aah. i am sorry i pasted the old code. My apologies. Please ignore the exit(0);

Comment: can you fix the question with proper code :P ?  it is actually useful to provide compilable code.  If the code is too big use http://pastebin.com

Comment: fork() twice; after the first fork exits, the second process becomes reparented under init. On BSD systems, you can use the daemon() libc call; why it doesn't exist everywhere is beyond my ken.

Comment: Oh, so the execv() needs to be called in the grand-child ? 
        
http://pastebin.com/9qK6gUQu
something like this ?

Comment: do i still need setsid ? also, should i establish a handler in the first child to know when the grandchild has terminated? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Commenting on some obvious errors:

- In the child process you execute `exit(0);` thus exiting the child process immediately. Remove this line.
- I think that for clarity you should call `execv()` like this `execv(argv[0], argv);`

**Edit:**
[Read the following](http://netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/linux-daemon-howto.html) to solve the problem with forking from a child process.

Comment: the absPath has the full absolute path of the file to be executed while argv[0] just the filename. Hence I dont think I could do that. Can I ?

Comment: Please ignore the exit(0), I forgot to update the code. It was there for my debugging purpose. Sorry.

Comment: According to http://linux.die.net/man/3/execv the first argument of execv should be the name of the file to be executed. The first argument to a process should be itself. Have a look at these to examples: http://www.cs.ecu.edu/karl/4630/spr01/example1.html and http://www.cs.ecu.edu/karl/4630/spr01/fork.html.

Comment: int execv(const char *path, char *const argv[]);
The first argument, by convention, should point to the filename associated with the file being executed. The array of pointers must be terminated by a NULL pointer. 

Confusing!

Comment: I did copy the above 2 lines from that website :S.

Comment: So, could you explain what is happening then?

Comment: the child process is executing, thats not the problem. The problem is that i am still not able to demonize the grandchild! its still being executed in my shell

Comment: amazing! the link you provided is exactly what I have been looking for. Thanks a ton! Such good explanation.

Answer (score 0):

As part of my Fat Controller application, I made a lib that will daemonise a process.   Download the source and take a look at daemonise.c - it should be relatively well commented but if you have any further questions then I'd be glad to help.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/fat-controller/files/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315240/background-process-daemon-in-c-not-execvp-ing

Comment: I just cant still seem to figure it out!