# Background Process (Daemon) in C not execvp() -ing

Tags: c, unix, process, background, exec

So, I am trying to run a background process and execvp from it.
When i enter cp /path/file /var/tmp, the process is not copying the file.

Here is my code for reference:

```
void cmd_bg(char command[])
{
        pid_t process_id = 0;
        pid_t sid = 0;
        char* argv[512];
        getArgv(command,argv);
        // Create child process
        process_id = fork();
        // Indication of fork() failure
        if (process_id < 0)
        {
                printf("fork failed!\n");
                // Return failure in exit status
                exit(1);
        }
        // PARENT PROCESS. Need to kill it.
        if (process_id > 0)
        {
                printf("process_id of child process %d \n", process_id);
                // return success in exit status
                exit(0);
        }
        //unmask the file mode
        umask(0);
        //set new session
        sid = setsid();
        if(sid < 0)
        {
                // Return failure
                exit(1);
        }
        // Change the current working directory to root.
        chdir("/");
        // Close stdin. stdout and stderr
        close(STDIN_FILENO);
        close(STDOUT_FILENO);
        close(STDERR_FILENO);


        execvp(argv[0],argv);

        }
}
void getArgv(char command[], char* argv[512])
{
        char *token;
        int count = 0;
        int pid = 0;
        int ex = 0;
        char *absPath;
        char pwdtemp[512];
        strcpy(pwdtemp,pwd);

        token = strtok(command, " ");
        while(token!=NULL)
        {
                argv[count++] = token;
                printf("%s\n",argv[count-1]);
                token = strtok(NULL," ");
        }
        argv[count] = '\0';
}
```

I sincerely hope someone can help me. Thanks!

**EDIT**: I FOUND THE SOLUTION. I CANT SELF-ANSWER BECAUSE I DONT HAVE 100 REPS YET.
ANYWAYS FOR PEOPLE WHO MIGHT VIEW THIS THREAD IN THE FUTURE:

OK. I figured out the problem.

Firstly I Commented out the

```
close(STDIN_FILENO);
close(STDOUT_FILENO);
close(STDERR_FILENO);
chdir("/");
```

Next, instead of calling the cmd_bg directly, I created:

```
void temp1(char command[])
{
    int pid = fork();
    if(pid==0)
        cmd_bg(command);

    else
        waitpid(-1, NULL, 0);
}
```

It seems to work now! Thanks a tonne for your input guys!

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of the code inline instead of on an external website.

Comment: Still incomplete. Where is main()? where is "pwd" defined? ... And `argv[count] = '\0';` should be `argv[count] = NULL;`

Answer (score 0):

Did you try without closing standard input, standard output, standard error

Answer (score 0):

I would check to see if execvp returns (it only returns on error), and see what errno it produces. That may help you track down the issue.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but how do I track when the process is not interacting with my shell ? (since its detached).

Comment: Sorry, please excuse me if its a simple question, I am new to C, I am a JAVA person!

Comment: If your system has syslog (linux should), you could try including syslog.h and calling syslog. Your logging will (probably) be appended to the end of /var/log/messages

Comment: There is no file called messages in that directory. I tried syslog (LOG_NOTICE, "XXX"); and included the syslog.h

Comment: Which distribution are you running? if it's debian (or ubuntu), try editing /etc/rsyslog.conf. there should be an entry like `*.=notice /var/log/messages` or `*.* /var/log/messages`. For other distributions, it may be /etc/syslog.conf

Answer (score 0):

any chance that you called your program `cp` ? if this is the case you `execvp()` will call the program over and over again, instead of `/bin/cp`. It also would be helpful to get the complete code.

Comment: Interesting! But no my program isnt called cp!