# Launch execlp as background process

Tags: c, exec

I'm trying to launch a program using `execlp`, continue with the program. and get control of the shell back.

This is what I did after some research from SO.

```
pid_t child;
pid_t sid;  
child = fork();
if (!child) {
    sid = setsid();
    if(!sid) {   
        exit(1);
    }
    execlp(RUN_EXE, RUN_EXE, SPEC_RUN.run_args[j], (char *)0);
}
```

But I'm unable to print anything after `execlp`. The execlp works correctly for me.

What do I need to do for the shell to return back?

Comment: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315240/background-process-daemon-in-c-not-execvp-ing`

This is one of the link I used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When successful, the [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) syscall *does not return* (it can return only on failure). So does the [execlp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) wrapper.

You usually want to `execve` inside the *child* process. And [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) could fail. You usually should call [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) before `fork`-ing . So code:

```
fflush(NULL);
pid_t p = fork();
if (p < 0) { perror("fork"); exit (EXIT_FAILURE); };
if (p == 0) { /* child process */
    execlp(RUN_EXE, RUN_EXE, SPEC_RUN.run_args[j], (char *)0);
    perror("execlp");
    fflush(NULL);
    _exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
/// continue in the parent process
printf("child process is %d\n", (int)p);
```

Don't forget to `wait` the child, e.g. using [waitpid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html)

See also [system(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html), [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html), [daemon(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/daemon.3.html), [posix_spawn](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/posix_spawn.html) and read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) (which has a nice chapter explaining these things).

Also, use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to understand how things work.

Comment: So, Is there a way to return ? I need to debug the rest of the code and gdb doesn't help me `print or getchar`.

Comment: Return from what? `execlp` does not return except on failure!

Comment: You do the same thing as I did. But with an error check, right?
Can I try to demonize the process or something? like `subprocess.Popen` in python

Comment: What do you mean by "return"? Please understand that `execve` *cannot return successfully!!!*

Comment: Ok, is there an another way other than `execve`?

Comment: Not really. You should take time to understand `fork` & `execve`. It is tricky. Take several hours to read about them.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch You have a bug - it's unsafe to call `exit` if `exec*` fails, it should instead be another `fflush` followed by `_exit`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you want to create a subprocess, run a program in that process, *and then wait for it to finish*.  Each of those three steps is its own operation on Unix, when working with system primitives directly.  You know about [fork()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) and [execlp()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execlp) already; the third step, waiting for a subprocess to finish, is done with [waitpid()](http://linux.die.net/man/2/waitpid) and its relatives.

Building on what Basile wrote, here is the missing piece:

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L /* strsignal */
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>

void run_program(void)
{
    int status;
    pid_t pid;

    fflush(0);

    /* create the subprocess */
    pid = fork();
    if (p < 0) { /* fork failed */
        perror("fork");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* in the child only, execute a program */
    if (p == 0) {
        execlp(RUN_EXE, RUN_EXE, SPEC_RUN.run_args[j], (char *)0);
        /* If execlp returns, it failed.  It is unsafe to call `exit` if this
           happens; you must instead use `_exit`.  This means you have to flush
           output manually. */
        fprintf(stderr, "execlp: %s: %s\n", RUN_EXE, strerror(errno));
        fflush(stderr);
        _exit(1);
    }

    /* in the parent, wait for the child to finish */
    if (waitpid(pid, &status, 0) != pid) {
        perror("waitpid");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* decode and report any failure of the child */
    if (WIFEXITED(status)) {
        if (WEXITSTATUS(status) == 0)
            return; /* success! */

        fprintf(stderr, "%s: unsuccessful exit %d\n",
                RUN_EXE, WEXITSTATUS(status));
        exit(1);
    }
    if (WIFSIGNALED(status)) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s%s\n",
                RUN_EXE,
                strsignal(WTERMSIG(status)),
                WCOREDUMP(status) ? " (core dumped)" : "");
        exit(1);
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: impossible exit status %04x\n",
            RUN_EXE, status);
    exit(1);
}
```

... If that looks like a giant ball of hair that you don't want to deal with, you should consider using the higher-level library functions [system()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) and/or [popen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) instead.  They have their own flaws -- most importantly, they go through `/bin/sh`, which is often Not What You Want -- but they are easier to work with in simple cases.